# How to use oauth with etrade api C

Tags: c++, oauth, etrade-api

I am making a C++ api using Etrade. They require you use Oauth1.01a

I have searched and I do not see any examples on the web. Can anyone assist??

Thank you very much!!!

```
bool GetRequestToken(CClientDetails &objClientDetails) throw (...);
bool GetAccessToken(CClientDetails &objClientDetails,string strVerifier) throw (...);
void RenewToken(CClientDetails &objClientDetails) throw (...);
void RevokeToken(CClientDetails &objClientDetails) throw (...);
string AuthorizeUrl(CClientDetails &objClientDetails) throw (...);

string GetProtectedResourse(CClientDetails &objClientDetails,string strUrl, HttpMethodConstants httpMethod = GETMethod, string postParameters = NULL) throw (...);
```

};
>

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up. The Authorize is the docs(v0) is wrong! If you are having problems with that step, that is probably it.

Here is the correct URL:
https://us.etrade.com/e/t/etws/authorize

I wrote a simple Node app called Trading Robo Monkey. If you have never used OAuth before, you can try to see if that was your problem by looking at the JS code

https://github.com/shikhirsingh/ETrade-API-Robo-Trading-Monkey-4-NodeJS